# Parameter pack with pervious parameter type match

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, variadic

So Im using a simple example to try to understand variadic templates and some tmp techniques. The example consists on a Timer class which has a toc() method. The toc methods its used to stop the timer and call a function which decides what to do (print it, save it in a variable...)

So I have coded this idea like this (ive removed the timing bits)

```
class VerbosePolicy {
public:
    VerbosePolicy() {}

    explicit VerbosePolicy(const std::string &message) : m_message(message) {}

    VerbosePolicy(VerbosePolicy &&other) { m_message = other.m_message; }

    void operator()(double time) { std::cout << m_message << time << std::endl; }

private:
    std::string m_message;
};

template <typename Policy, typename... Args> class Timer {
public:
    Timer(Args... args) : m_policy(Policy(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {}

    void toc(double time) { m_policy(time); }

private:
    Policy m_policy;
};
```

Here I create a Timer with a Policy and call the ctor of the Policy with the parameter pack. This way I can control how the Policy works (for example, I could pass a variable and store there the result).

Now, I want to use this

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string string = "Elapsed time";
    Timer<VerbosePolicy> timer(string);
    timer.toc(1.0);
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler is not able to determine that the string is part of the parameter pack, and its trying to match it to the Policy time, which fails.

I have tried adding a default argument for the Timer ctor

```
Timer(Args... args, Policy policy = Policy())
```

But this also fails, as its still trying to match de string to the policy type (in this case, it tries to call the second ctor, which fails because its marked as explicit. If I remove it, it compiles, but works wrong because the policy value its incorrect).

Everything works fine if I write

```
Timer<VerbosePolicy, std::string> timer(string)
```

as it doesn't need to deduce the variadic template anymore.

Is there anyway I can avoid writing the std::string?
Thanks!

EDIT:

So to be complete and address some of the problems talked in the comments of the valid answer, I have been trying to deactivate the variadic constructor when the parameter its of the same type as the Timer, without success.

My approach has been

```
template <typename T, typename... Tail> struct first_of { using type = T; };

template <typename Policy> class Timer {
public:
  template <
      typename... CArgs,
      std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<Timer<Policy>,
                                     typename first_of<CArgs...>::type>::value,
                       int> = 0>
  Timer(CArgs &&... args) : m_policy(std::forward<CArgs>(args)...) {}

  Timer(const Timer<Policy> &other) : m_policy(other.m_policy) {}

  void toc(double time) { m_policy(time); }

private:
  Policy m_policy;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::string string = "Elapsed time";
  Timer<VerbosePolicy> timer(string);
  Timer<VerbosePolicy> timer2(timer);
  timer.toc(1.0);
}
```

But the compiler still tries to use the variadic constructor for timer2. Im not sure why its trying to do this, since the two types passed to std::is_same should be equal, and therefore the ctor should be deactivated.

What am I misunderstanding?

Thanks again!

Comment: `m_policy(Policy(std::forward<Args>(args)...))` should be `m_policy(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`. No need to specify the type. For example, if `m_x` is and `int`, you don't write `m_x(int(5))` in the member initializer list.

Comment: I would go for `Timer(Policy p) :m_policy(std::move(p))` with usage `Timer<VerbosePolicy> timer(VerbosePolicy("Elapsed time"));` (and in C++17, you might even remove `<VerbosePolicy>`).

Comment: Its an option I have already study. But I didnt want to repeat the VerbosePolicy, so that why I started to study another solution. Thanks for tip though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to make your constructor template instead?

Like :

```
template <typename Policy> class Timer {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    Timer(Args && ... args) : m_policy(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    void toc(double time) { m_policy(time); }

private:
    Policy m_policy;
};
```

Btw, you are using `std::forward` in the wrong way. What you are doing is that :

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T v) {
    std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

In such code, `T` is a non reference value. So forward it here means : `T&&` so it is the same as "move"

if you want to forward reference, you must use forwarding reference :

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T &&v) {
    std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

If the argument is a lvalue reference, here `T` is a `T&` and if the argument is a rvalue reference, `T` is a `T` and by forwarding reference v is respectively a `T& &&`so a  `T&` and `T &&` so a `T&&` ;)

EDIT : 
As said in commentary, this code does not work when you give a Timer to the constructor.
There is some way to avoid this issue, SFINAE can help you for example ;)

EDIT 2 :
You want to keep a track of your `Args ...` as you said in commentary.

Let's say you have a class like that :

```
template<typename ...Args>
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Args... args) : noexcept m_tuple{std::move(args)...} {}
private:
    std::tuple<Args...> m_tuple;
};
```

You want to deduce type : there is two ways :

1) Before C++ 17 :

```
template<typename ...Args>
Foo<Args...> make_foo(Args ...args) {
    return {args...};
}

auto d = make_foo(5, 3.0); // Foo<int, double>
```

2) After c++ 17

```
template<typename ...Args>
Foo(Args...) -> Foo<Args...>;

Foo foo{3.0, "Lol"s}; // Foo<double, std::string>
```

The name for this is deduction guide.

Comment: There are some issues with that kind of catch all constructor: exact match for `Timer(Timer&)` so better match than the default copy constructor. SFINAE might solve that, or adding some tag as `piecewise_construct_t`.

Comment: That was fast. Indeed, I didn't tried that solution. Works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarod42 : You are true, I made an edit to give some pointers to fix that issue ;)

Comment: jarod42. would that be solved using a make_timer function instead of a ctor? Also, what would happen if I wanted to store the parameter pack in the Timer? I would need again to define the Args for the whole class, with the same problem as in the original question

Comment: @jjcasmar I do not see how a make_timer function can solve this issue. The idea is to detect if Args... == Timer. And if so, you disable this function to allows the copy constructor to do this job. 
If you want to store the parameter pack in the timer, there is several way to do this, and define Args for the whole class the same way you did the first is one way, and here, you can use a make_timer function or template deduction guide ;)

Comment: But if I add the Args to the whole class for defining the tuple, I would have the same problem as in the original question, right?

Comment: Why would you have a problem? In your question you told explicitely that using `Timer<Policy, string>` works. So there is no problem, no?

Comment: Sure, it works. But I was trying to avoid specifying the string. As I said, its some study cases Im doing. Somehow I think that it should be possible to deduce the string type. Maybe its not possible :)

Comment: I tried to do the sfinae thing to deactivate the ctor when passing another Timer, but Ive been unable. Ive updated the question accordingly

Comment: It is a different question, so, please ask a different question ;)